# Deleted com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist in Mavericks, how to get it back?

Tags: macos, dns

I already had trouble with DNS not resolving for all apps except Chrome, in my troubleshooting I for some reason deleted com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist
Deleting this file did not help in any way..
Could someone post the text to 10.9 com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist? I understand I will have to change permissions etc on the file.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! You had two questions here — I've removed the second one: feel free to search for the answer to that specifically and ask it separately if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the contents of my /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist from OS X 10.9.1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.apple.mDNSResponder</string>
    <key>OnDemand</key>
    <false/>
    <key>InitGroups</key>
    <false/>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>_mdnsresponder</string>
    <key>GroupName</key>
    <string>_mdnsresponder</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/sbin/mDNSResponder</string>
    </array>
    <key>MachServices</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.mDNSResponder</key>
        <true/>
               <key>com.apple.mDNSResponder.dnsproxy</key>
               <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>Sockets</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Listeners</key>
        <dict>
            <key>SockFamily</key>
            <string>Unix</string>
            <key>SockPathName</key>
            <string>/var/run/mDNSResponder</string>
            <key>SockPathMode</key>
            <integer>438</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>EnableTransactions</key>
    <true/>
    <key>BeginTransactionAtShutdown</key>
    <true/>
    <key>POSIXSpawnType</key>
    <string>Interactive</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

It'd probably be worth running a permissions repair after restoring the file.

Comment: Sorted thanks pasted, repaired and launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist
I now have DNS and wont need to reinstall

Answer (score -2):

Label
    com.apple.mDNSResponder
    OnDemand

change falsed by true in this command

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.